# Creating a Time class in Java

Tags: java, time

So my task is to create a Time class that holds an hour value and a minute value to represent a time.  I'll be using "military time", so 12:01 am is 0001 and 1 pm is 1300.  I may assume valid military times range from 0000 to 2359. Valid standard times range from 12:00 am to 11:59 pm.  Time should include two constructors:

Time() - Default constructor that sets the time to 1200.
Time(int h, int m) - If h is between 1 and 23 inclusive, set the hour to h. Otherwise, set the hour to 0. If m is between 0 and 59 inclusive, set the minutes to m. Otherwise, set the minutes to 0.
Time should include the following methods:

String toString() - Returns the time as a String of length 4 in the format: 0819. Notice that if the hour or minute is one digit, it should print a zero first. For example, 6 should print as 06.

String convert() - Returns the time as a String converted from military time to standard time. For example, 0545 becomes 5:45 am and 1306 becomes 1:06 pm.

void increment() - Advances the time by one minute. Remember that 60 minutes = 1 hour. Therefore, if your time was 0359, and you add one minute, it becomes 0400. 2359 should increment to 0000.

This is what I've written (with the exception of the main method):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Time
{

    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    public Time()
    {
        hour = 12;
        minute = 0;
    }


    public Time(int h, int m)
    {
        if ( h >= 1 && h <= 23)
            h = hour;
        else 
            hour = 0;
        if ( m >= 0 && m <= 59)
            m = minute;
        else 
            minute = 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";
        if ( hour < 10 && minute < 10)
            s = "0" + hour + "0" + minute;
        else if ( hour < 10 && minute > 10)
            s = "0" + hour + minute;
        else if ( hour > 10 && minute < 10)
            s = hour + "0" + minute;
        else if ( hour == 0)
            s = "0" + hour + minute;
        else if ( minute == 0)
            s = hour + "0" + minute;

        return s;

    }

    public String convert()
    {
        String c = "";
        if ( hour > 12)
            c = "0" + (24 - hour) + minute + "pm";
        else
            c = hour + minute + "am";
        return c;
    }

    public void increment()
    {
        minute++;
        if (minute == 60)
        {
            hour++;
            minute = 0;
        }
        else if ( hour == 24)
            hour = 0;

    }

     public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException
     {

      Time time1 = new Time(14, 56);
      System.out.println("time1: " + time1);
      System.out.println("convert time1 to standard time: " + time1.convert());
      System.out.println("time1: " + time1);
      System.out.print("increment time1 five times: ");
      time1.increment();
      time1.increment();
      time1.increment();
      time1.increment();
      time1.increment();
      System.out.println(time1 + "\n");

      Time time2 = new Time(-7, 12);
      System.out.println("time2: " + time2);
      System.out.print("increment time2 67 times: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < 67; i++)
       time2.increment();
      System.out.println(time2);
      System.out.println("convert to time2 standard time: " + time2.convert());
      System.out.println("time2: " + time2 + "\n");


      Time time3 = new Time(5, 17);
      System.out.println("time3: " + time3);
      System.out.print("convert time3: ");
      System.out.println(time3.convert());

      Time time4 = new Time(12, 15);
      System.out.println("\ntime4: " + time4);
      System.out.println("convert time4: " + time4.convert());

      Time time5 = new Time(0, 15);
      System.out.println("\ntime5: " + time5);
      System.out.println("convert time5: " + time5.convert());

      Time time6 = new Time(24, 15);
      System.out.println("\ntime6: " + time6);
      System.out.println("convert time6: " + time6.convert());

      Time time7 = new Time(23,59);
      System.out.println("\ntime7: " + time7);
      System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());
      time7.increment();
      System.out.println("increment time7: " + time7);
      System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());

     }

}
```

The output should be as follows:

```
time1: 1456
convert time1 to standard time: 2:56 pm
time1: 1456
increment time1 five times: 1501

time2: 0012
increment time2 67 times: 0119
convert to time2 standard time: 1:19 am
time2: 0119

time3: 0517
convert time3: 5:17 am

time4: 1215
convert time4: 12:15 pm

time5: 0015
convert time5: 12:15 am

time6: 0015
convert time6: 12:15 am

time7: 2359
convert time7: 11:59 pm
increment time7: 0000
convert time7: 12:00 am
```

My current output is:

```
time1: 0000
convert time1 to standard time: 0am
time1: 0000
increment time1 five times: 0005

time2: 0000
increment time2 67 times: 0107
convert to time2 standard time: 8am
time2: 0107

time3: 0000
convert time3: 0am

time4: 0000
convert time4: 0am

time5: 0000
convert time5: 0am

time6: 0000
convert time6: 0am

time7: 0000
convert time7: 0am
increment time7: 0001
convert time7: 1am
```

My compiler is telling me that there are issues all over and I can't figure out where.  If somebody could please take a look and help me figure out what's wrong, it'd be very helpful.  Thank You!

Comment: constructor assignment is wrong it should be reversed!!

Comment: toString() is not having condition for few cases i.e. **hour > 10 && minute > 10**

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the constructor , you are not assigning the values to the class variable instead you are assigning to method variable, this is what your code looks like,

```
public Time(int h, int m)
    {
        if ( h >= 1 && h <= 23)
            h = hour;
        else 
            hour = 0;
        if ( m >= 0 && m <= 59)
            m = minute;
        else 
            minute = 0;
    }
```

instead use the below Time constructor,

```
public Time(int h, int m)
        {
            if ( h >= 1 && h <= 23)
                hour =h;
            else
                hour = 0;
            if ( m >= 0 && m <= 59)
                minute = m;
            else
                minute = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to fix the error with the Constructor, now I just have to figure out what's wrong with increment and convert.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor assignment is reversed as said in previous answers.

Also your `toString` method, add an ultimate `else` clause where you do
    `s = hour + minute` ;

Answer (score 1):

your issue is in **constructor, toString()** and **convert()** method.

code changes accordingly are :

```
public MultiLevel(int h, int m)
{
    if ( h >= 1 && h <= 23)
        hour = h;
    else 
        hour = 0;
    if ( m >= 0 && m <= 59)
        minute = m;
    else 
        minute = 0;
}

public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    if ( hour < 10 && minute < 10)
        s = "0" + hour + "0" + minute;
    else if ( hour < 10 && minute > 10)
        s = "0" + hour + minute;
    else if ( hour > 10 && minute < 10)
        s = hour + "0" + minute;
    else if ( hour > 10 && minute > 10)
        s = hour  +""+ minute;
    else if ( hour == 0)
        s = "0" + hour + minute;
    else if ( minute == 0)
        s = hour + "0" + minute;

    return s;

}

public String convert()
{
    String c = "";

    if ( hour > 12)
    {
        if(hour >10){
            if((hour - 12) == 12)
                 c = (hour - 12) +":"+ minute + "am";
            else
               c = (hour - 12) +":"+ minute + "pm";
        }
        else
        {
            c = "0" + (hour - 12) +":"+ minute + "pm";
        }
    }
    else
        c = hour +":"+ minute + "am";
    if(minute == 0)
    {
        c= c.substring(0, c.length()-2)+"0"+c.substring(c.length()-2, c.length());
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Time
{

    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    public Time()
    {
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
    }


    public Time(int h, int m)
    {
        if ( h >= 1 && h <= 23)
            hour =h;
        else
            hour = 0;
        if ( m >= 0 && m <= 59)
            minute = m;
        else
            minute = 0;
    }



    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "";
        if ( hour < 10 && minute < 10)
            s = "0" + hour + "0" + minute;
        else if ( hour < 10 && minute > 10)
            s = "0" + hour + minute;
        else if ( hour > 10 && minute < 10)
            s = hour + "0" + minute;
        else if ( hour > 10 && minute > 10)
            s = hour +""+ minute;
        else if ( hour == 0)
            s = "0" + hour + minute;
        else if ( minute == 0)
            s = hour + "0" + minute;

        return s;

    }

    public String convert()
    {
        String c = "";

        if (hour >11)
        {
            if (hour == 12)
            {
                c = hour +":"+ minute + " PM";
            }
            if (hour > 12)
            {
                c = (hour - 12) +":"+ minute + " PM";
            }
        }
        else if (hour == 0)
        {
            c = (hour+12) +":"+ minute + " AM";
        }

        else
             c = hour +":"+ minute + " AM";











        if(minute < 10)
        {
            c= c.substring(0, c.length()-4)+"0"+minute+" "+c.substring(c.length()-2, c.length());
        }
        return c;
    }
    public void increment()
    {
        if (hour == 23 && minute == 59)
        {
            hour = 0;
            minute = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        minute++;
        if (minute == 60)
        {
            hour++;
            minute = 0;
        }
        else if ( hour == 24)
            hour = 0;
        }
    }

     public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException
     {

         Time time1 = new Time(14, 56);
          System.out.println("time1: " + time1);
          System.out.println("convert time1 to standard time: " + time1.convert());
          System.out.println("time1: " + time1);
          System.out.print("increment time1 five times: ");
          time1.increment();
          time1.increment();
          time1.increment();
          time1.increment();
          time1.increment();
          System.out.println(time1 + "\n");

          Time time2 = new Time(-7, 12);
          System.out.println("time2: " + time2);
          System.out.print("increment time2 67 times: ");
          for (int i = 0; i < 67; i++)
           time2.increment();
          System.out.println(time2);
          System.out.println("convert to time2 standard time: " + time2.convert());
          System.out.println("time2: " + time2 + "\n");


          Time time3 = new Time(5, 1);
          System.out.println("time3: " + time3);
          System.out.print("convert time3: ");
          System.out.println(time3.convert());

          Time time4 = new Time(12, 15);
          System.out.println("\ntime4: " + time4);
          System.out.println("convert time4: " + time4.convert());

          Time time5 = new Time(0, 15);
          System.out.println("\ntime5: " + time5);
          System.out.println("convert time5: " + time5.convert());

          Time time6 = new Time(24, 15);
          System.out.println("\ntime6: " + time6);
          System.out.println("convert time6: " + time6.convert());

          Time time7 = new Time(23,59);
          System.out.println("\ntime7: " + time7);
          System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());
          time7.increment();
          System.out.println("increment time7: " + time7);
          System.out.println("convert time7: " + time7.convert());

     }

}
```

Here you go. I had the same assignment, this gave me 100%. I cleaned up a lot of your code, it was a big pile of spaghetti. The biggest error you has was that you initialized hour to 12 instead of zero right in the beginning. You had a few errors here and there, of which I forgot to note, but this will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

**I Have made some improvement from above code**

> Add a exception class and string builder and suggest new things to improve in the code

**Exception Code is below**

```
  public class InvalidTimeException extends Exception {

    public InvalidTimeException() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public InvalidTimeException(String arg0, Throwable arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public InvalidTimeException(String arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public InvalidTimeException(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public InvalidTimeException(Throwable arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }





}
```

**Improvise code**

```
import com.vinay.timeclass.exceptions.InvalidTimeException;

/**
 * @author Dell
 *
 */
public class Time {

    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    public Time() {
        hour = 0;
        minute =0;
    }

    public Time(int hour, int minute) throws InvalidTimeException {
        if(hour > 24 || minute > 60)
            throw new InvalidTimeException(" Hour cannot be greater than 24 and minute cannot be greater than 24 ");

        if(hour >=1 && hour<=23) 
            this.hour = hour;
        else 
            this.hour = 0;


        if (minute >=0 && minute <=59) {
            this.minute =  minute;
        } else {
            minute = 0; 
        }


    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder timeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if(hour < 10 && minute < 10) {
            timeBuilder.append("0").append(hour).append(":").append("0").append(minute);
        } 
        else if (hour < 10 && minute > 10) {
            timeBuilder.append("0").append(hour).append(":").append(minute);
        }
        else if (hour > 10 && minute < 10) {
            timeBuilder.append(hour).append(":").append("0").append(minute);
        }else if(hour > 10 && minute > 10) {
            timeBuilder.append(hour).append(":").append(minute);
        }else if(hour == 0) {
            if(minute < 10)
            timeBuilder.append("0").append(hour).append(":0").append(minute);
            else            
            timeBuilder.append(hour).append(":").append(minute);
        }else if (minute == 0) {
            if(minute < 10)
                timeBuilder.append("0").append(hour).append(":0").append(minute);
                else            
                timeBuilder.append(hour).append(":0").append(minute);
        }


        return timeBuilder.toString();
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) throws InvalidTimeException{
        if(hour>24)
            throw new InvalidTimeException("Hour cannot be greater than 24");

        this.hour = hour;

    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute) throws InvalidTimeException{
        if(minute>60)
            throw new InvalidTimeException("Minute cannot be greater than 60");
        this.minute = minute;
    }

    public String convert(){

        StringBuilder timeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if(hour > 11) {
            if(hour == 12) {
                timeBuilder.append(hour).append(":").append(minute).append(" PM");
            }else if(hour > 12) {
                timeBuilder.append(hour-12).append(":").append(minute).append(" PM");
            }

        }else if(hour == 0) {
            timeBuilder.append(hour+12).append(":").append(minute).append(" AM");
        }else {
            timeBuilder.append(hour).append(":").append(minute).append(" AM");
        }

        String timeString = timeBuilder.toString();
        if(minute < 10) {
            timeString = timeString.substring(0, timeString.length()-4)+"0"+minute+" "+timeString.substring(timeString.length()-2, timeString.length());
        }
        return timeString;

    }


    public void increment() {
        if(hour== 23 && minute == 59) {
            hour = 0;
            minute = 0;
        }else {
            minute ++;
            if(minute == 60) {
                hour++;
                minute = 0;
                if(hour == 24) {
                    hour =0;
                }
            }
            else if(hour == 24) {
                hour = 0;
            }
        }
    }








}
```